# HTML to PDF - element dimensions in inches not as expected

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing, puppeteer

#### Update

The issue is related to Bootstrap 4. For some reason if I set the page to a certain size and then add an element (div, image) within for a similar size, it will be smaller. I didn't figure out what resulted it and all this happened in Vanilla BS4.

I downgraded to BS3 and it worked as expected.

---

#### Old issue

I am needing to generate PDFs. I am using `in` as a measurement for components. I noticed an anomaly where the printed item was shorter than the width I expected.

My calculations are based on [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths) which states 96px = 1in. But that is not what I see.

#### Details

In CSS I set the page size to letter (also tried specifying the dimensions manually in inches).

```
@page {
  margin: 0.25in 0.5in;
  size: letter;
}
```

Then I have a letterhead image.There is an validation for this image to not exceed the window allowed for a #10 double window envelop and thus I need to predict its length which I use `pixels/96`. Then I noticed that a letterhead I expected to overlap the window didn't even come close for an overlap. Digging further I noticed the meassurements seemed to be off.

In the image below I have set the page as `letter (8.5in x 11in)` and the width of the image to `10in` and it has yet not overflowed. I made sure that the page size is affecting the printout by changing it to 3x3 and as expected made a smaller page.

1. Can I use `in` as a measurement for print to determine their  printed sizes?
2. Is there some thing I am missing that is not setting the document size properly?
3. Is there some thing that can effect the `in` measurement unit.

Notes:

- Page is vanilla bootstrap with some minor css changes
- Final PDF generated with a Node JS app that runs Puppeteer (what I see in the generated PDF is similar or very close to what I see in the browser print).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Ziyan you can use @media print in your css and make the way you want to look your page while printing it [See Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

Comment: I have tried it... The need to use `@media print` is in my understanding when you need to differentiate the print vs screen. But that is not the case. What I am seeing is when I set the document width to 8.5in and set the style for an image 10in its not even filling the width of the page. That is my problem.